# Suitescript - How to know the fields ID in sub record - Inventory transfer

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to create a restlet that can create a bin transfer.
My code is almost complete, I can create line item fields also.

The only thing that I can't do is to fill up the inventory detail because I don't know the fields in Subrecords. How can inpect the field id in the sub records line items columns?

```
define([ 'N/record', 'N/search'], function(r, s) {
function onSendRequst(context) 
{

    var rec = r.create({
        type: context.recordtype,
        isDynamic: true
    });

    rec.setValue( 'location', context.from_location_id );
    rec.setValue( 'transferlocation', context.to_location_id );
    rec.setValue( 'memo', context.memo );     

    for( var i = 0; i < context.inventory.length; i++)
    {
        var inv = context.inventory;

        // Create sublist Record
        rec.selectNewLine({
            sublistId: 'inventory',
            line: i+1
        });

        rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'inventory',
            fieldId: 'item',
            value: inv[i].item_ndc
        });
        rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'inventory',
            fieldId: 'adjustqtyby',
            value: inv[i].qty
        });

        rec.commitLine({
            sublistId: 'inventory'
        });


        // **CREATE A SUB RECORD**

        var itemInventorySubrecord = r.getSublistSubrecord({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
            line: x
        });
    }
    var recordId = rec.save({
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: true
    });
    return recordId;
}

return {
    post: onSendRequst
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the field IDs for inventory detail under the Inventory Detail entry in the Records Browser. Subrecords are available in the SuiteScript Records Browser just like regular records.

Comment: For the main record which id would it be tranid or externalid. Or some other id? That is how do I find the primary key of the record?